# Staggered Transition Effect with HeadlessUI; "Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm trying to create a staggered load in effect with HeadlessUI's `<Transition>` component. I'm close to getting it to work, however, `Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.` is the error I keep getting. What's the appropriate way to handle this?

```js
export default function Card() {
  const timer = (ms: number) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
  const checkSection = async (section: string) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < renderRoutine.sections.length; i++) {
      if (renderRoutine.sections[i].name === section) {
        await timer(300);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
  return (
{renderRoutine.sections.map(async(section, idx) => (
        <Transition
          key={section.name}
          as={Fragment}
          appear={true}
          show={await checkSection(section.name)}
          //props
        >
        // Other elements
        </ Transition>
)}
)};
```

Edit: Implemented Andrey Smolko's solution, but now get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then i think you need to use useEffect for that:

```js
// add state
const [showArray, setShowArray] = useState(renderRoutine.sections.map(e=>false)) 

useEffect(()=>{
// when all promises are resolved then update state
// that works only if timeouts have the same values as in your snippet
Promise.all(renderRoutine.sections.map(section=>checkSection(section.name))).then(res=>setShowArray(res))
},[])

...
show={showArray[idx]}
...
```

but I think you may simplify checkSection and remove if statement